# filter by attribute woocommerce collapse after 5 attributes -> show more

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I want to limit the filter attributes shown on the shop page. I found this

```
function my_theme_scripts_function() {
echo "<scipt>
var limit = 10;
var list = $("#attribute_list");
var more = 0;

function tricky_hide(){
    var morec = 0;
    $("li", list).each(function(index) {
        if (index >= limit) {
            $(this).hide();      
            morec = index - limit + 1;
        }
    });
    
    if (!more) more = morec;

    if (more) {
        list.append('<li class="more">' + more + ' more</li>');
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
    

if (tricky_hide()) {
    list.live("mouseover", function() {
        $("li", list).each(function(index) {
            $(this).show();
        });
        $("li.more", list).hide();
    });

    list.live("mouseout", function() {
        tricky_hide();
    });
}
</script>
"
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','my_theme_scripts_function');
```

i want to add a button or a text link with "show more"

[collapse after 5 attributes -> show more](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROZDc.jpg)

Comment: Have you wrote the code?

Comment: no, i found it here https://xtemos.com/forums/topic/sidebar-filter-attributes-collapse/

Comment: Have you debugged the code by yourself before asking? What have you found out? :)

Comment: yes. unfortunately, not much. no errors appear in the console. all filter attributes have #attribute_list

Comment: Can you please share what you've exaclty debugged? I need something to stick on...

Comment: "No problems have been detected in the workspace."